# Running into an error after upgrading springboot from 2.3.9 to 2.6.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, upgrade

After upgrading from springboot 2.3.9 to 2.6.6 I have a failing tests with the following error,

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
 <Unstarted application context org.springframework.boot.test.context.assertj.AssertableApplicationContext[startupFailure=org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException]>
to have a single bean of type:
 <com.air.dx.range.application.RangeApplicationService>:
but context failed to start:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'IRoRangeRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDialect' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

One observation after upgrading,

The class **ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer** from spring-boot-test jar is modified to **ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer**.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, we ran into the same issue. Weird that this seems to not be documented anywhere (or I couldn't find it)

Comment: Please post your pom.xml as this clearly a dependency problem

Comment: Which database are you using in failing test?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a legal assumption and it is the case. Actually, in spring-boot 2.4.0 `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` [was already marked as deprecated](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test/2.4.4/org/springframework/boot/test/context/ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.html) in favor `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer`. Just be aware that `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` no longer exists in spring-boot starting from 3.0.0.
So you can just switch to `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer` and that should be enough.